# remove object from array which have same values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm initializing an array with dynamic objects and result is following

```
var arr = [
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0}
];
```

now i want to remove any object from this array but not finding proper solution. Can someone please help me how to do it.

Comment: This will remove any.`arr=[]`.

Comment: You need to find index of object, then use splice method to remove the object from array.

Comment: @Alexandru arr = [] will empty whole array, that's what I don't want.

Comment: @KashifHussain, You don't specify which objects you want.

Comment: @VijayRaheja initially when there are no values set in any object as you can see so I can't find index. Array will be exactly what I have shown above and at this stage I have to remove any single object from inside array. If you have solution for that please help

Comment: @KashifHussain what is a criteria for object to be deleted?

Comment: @brk arr.splice(1, 1) will remove first member object from array, but user can click on any of the object to remove

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Technically that's not removing, you are just assigning a new array reference to the variable `arr`. If there are other variables holding the reference to the old array, those arrays won't get updated.

Comment: @KashifHussain Then pass the index to arr.splice(). That will make it dynamic.

Comment: @Walk there's a slider from value 1 - 10, user drags slide and presses a button, then number of forms open (in response to slider value), each form has a delete button so at any time user can click to remove respective form. As initially all form are initiated with default values (or null values) which are shown above. there's comes my problem. Hope you understand all scenario, if still its not clear please let me know I'll explain further

Comment: @KashifHussain I think I got you. Do you have to create objects with all empty values? Maybe you can add some ID value so each of those objects are unique? Maybe you can use index of element which user clicks as an index for your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys thank you so much for your help. I have found solution to this issue, following is what I wanted.

this is my array with initial values set.

```
var arr = [
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0}
];
```

and I I can remove any object like this:

```
arr.splice(arr[index], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to remove any object from this array but not finding proper
>   solution

You can use splice method, It accepts the index(start) of the to be removed element and also the `deleteCount` that is number of elements to be removed from the starting index

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "A",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "B",
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "C",
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "D",
    quantity: 4
  }
];
arr.splice(1, 1)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

at the beginning you must know which object you want to delete it (for example the object whose id = x)

then you can use this code

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e){ return e.id != x });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that **filter your arr Array** which has non-empty values like this-:

```
 var arr = [
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0},
    {id: "", name: "", quantity: 0}
];

 arr = arr.filter((obj)=>obj.id!==''); // you can use any field to filter 
 arr = arr.filter((obj)=>obj.id!=='' || obj.name!=='');// multiple fields to filter
```

**Now your arr variable will be updated with new array of objects with non-empty fields**